# Is it ALWAYS transparent to increase the size of a MYSQL column?

Tags: mysql, alter

It appears to me that if I make a column larger (i.e. `varchar(255)` to `varchar(512)`) that these kinds of changes are always transparent.

1. existing data in that column would be identical, and
2. selects and other mysql statement would work the same in either case, and require no changes?

It's that a valid assumption? I'm about to make a field larger that has data in it (with `alter`) and I want to be sure that after the change, things will function and appear exactly as they do now (except after, I can push in larger fields).

Comment: If you *shorten* the column, data will be truncated. If you widen the column, data is intact.

Comment: Just variable length character columns or other types?

Comment: Ryan I mean text types in general like char, varchar

Comment: maybe useful: [3 Gotchas When Changing a MySQL Column Attribute](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2012/06/29/3-gotchas-when-changing-a-mysql-column-attribute/). The default null would have caught me out.

Comment: Thanks Ryan I'll check it out....

Comment: Assuming you don't screw up with null / not null etc, data is intact. The only time when data is modified is when the column is made shorter. If you have a 100 character string and you modify the column to be 50 chars in length  - data gets truncated. Same goes for other data types. If you want to increase an integer, everything is fine. Same goes for floats etc.

Comment: If yo widen the column, queries that previously failed will no longer fail. It can't be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Data will remain the same if the column is made larger (e.g. `VARCHAR(100)` to `VARCHAR(200)`).

Queries, such as `SELECT`s should work as expected, however you should consider relationships this field has with others, internally and externally.

- Is this field displayed in an external application which is set to only handle displaying *N* characters and will now be expected to handle *N+X* characters?
- Is this field the input to another query or procedure which is only expecting a field of length *N* will not be able to handle length *N+X*?